# Yii2 and Google Client

Tags: composer-php, yii2, google-client

I use Yii2 and "google/client" attached by composer. The problem is that the google library has class names with namespaces. E. g. Client.php has the class Google_Client. Composer's autoloader doesn't work with that syntax. How can I make it work?

Comment: Please, provide your code.

Answer (score 1):

put

```
use google\apiclient;
```

in the namespace

Then use:

```
set_include_path(Yii::$app->BasePath  . '/vendor/google/apiclient/src');
```

Also put a backslash before classes to resolve to the namespace e.g.

`$analytics = new \Google_Service_Analytics($client);`